# ReactNative's FlatList calls renderItem more times than windowSize specifies

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using `FlatList` to render a list. I've configured to display only one row at a time by using `pagingEnabled={true}` and rendering cells that are take up the full size of the parent.

I've also set `windowSize={2}` and `initialNumToRender={1}`. In my `renderItem` function, I'm logging every call with `console.log`.

When the component loads, I see one log statement in `renderItem` for each item on my data array, which means every cell is getting pre-rendered.

The result is a delay loading the Component. Shouldn't cells only be getting rendered by the amount `windowSize` specifies?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, looks like there is a bug in FlatList and VirtualizedList: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18142
But I don't know why don't want to solve, I test with a little app that only render a list of numbers, and I had the same problem. I didn't fixed it at all, but it helped me improve the performance: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Note: Is very important implement: `getItemLayout` and put `removeClippedSubviews={true}` because it improves performance considerably.

Pd: I recommend you this component: https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

I hope I've helped you.
¡Greetings!